# Filter unique combination in the list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, dictionary

So, I got list full of dictionaries where I have two names (name00 and name01). These are names of linked clusters and there are always all combinations available. Combinations can be created from 2 or more clusters and there can be more combinations available in results variable.

In this example I have linked cluster with 3 different names (1,2,3) and with 2 different names (4,5) but it can be much more.

I need to filter the results so I get only unique combination (of name00 and name01 both ways) and only for one of the clusters. For example, we can throw away combination of test2-test3 in the example if test1 is selected as main.

I hope the example will make it clear.

```
results = [
{ 'name00': 'test1', 'name01': 'test2' },
{ 'name00': 'test1', 'name01': 'test3' },
{ 'name00': 'test2', 'name01': 'test1' },
{ 'name00': 'test2', 'name01': 'test3' },
{ 'name00': 'test3', 'name01': 'test1' },
{ 'name00': 'test3', 'name01': 'test2' },
{ 'name00': 'test4', 'name01': 'test5' },
{ 'name00': 'test5', 'name01': 'test4' }
]

# Desired result

results = [
{ 'name00': 'test1', 'name01': 'test2' },
{ 'name00': 'test1', 'name01': 'test3' },
{ 'name00': 'test4', 'name01': 'test5' }
]
```

Comment: This is not quite clear.  Are you guaranteed that all `n!` possibilities will be included?  If not, what are the necessary conditions for removing a combination, as you've done with 2-3.  If the cluster is 1234, what is the desired output?

Comment: Why is this being handled in a dict format?  I would think that the easy solution would be to makes sets of the cluster closures, and then simply generate the MST (minimum spanning tree) from that.

Comment: @Prune if it is all combination of 1234 then desired output is 12, 13, 14
Unfortunately, I am just working with the data that were passed in the script. I can control the format but only if I convert it manually.

Comment: I still have an open question on the completeness.  For example, if 7-8-9 is a cluster, will we have all 6 pairs in the given dict?

Comment: @Prune yes, 78, 79, 87, 89, 97, 98 and the result should be 78, 79 (or 87, 89 or 97, 98, it really doesn't matter which one is selected as the 'main')

Answer (score 1):

With all of the pairs appearing in the list, the implementation should be simple enough.

Sort the list.  The "lower" labels will come to the front.  In particular, the first entry will be a viable main element.  Put every such link into the results list, keeping track of the second elements.  Then pass over the links starting with "other" names.  Repeat this until you've covered the entire original list.  Here's a painfully detailed version:

```
start = [
    { 'name00': 'test1', 'name01': 'test2' },
    { 'name00': 'test1', 'name01': 'test3' },
    { 'name00': 'test2', 'name01': 'test1' },
    { 'name00': 'test2', 'name01': 'test3' },
    { 'name00': 'test3', 'name01': 'test1' },
    { 'name00': 'test3', 'name01': 'test2' },
    { 'name00': 'test4', 'name01': 'test5' },
    { 'name00': 'test5', 'name01': 'test4' }
]

result = []

start.sort(key=lambda link: link["name00"]+link["name01"]) 

for link in start:
    print(link)

link_key = None
pos = 0
while pos < len(start):

    other_name = []

    link = start[pos]
    if not link_key:
        link_key = link['name00']

    # Gather all of the links that start with the lowest name.
    # Keep track of the other names for later use.
    while start[pos]['name00'] == link_key:
        link = start[pos]
        result.append(link)
        other_name.append(link["name01"])
        pos += 1

    # Now is "later" ... ignore all links that start with other names.
    while pos < len(start) and              \
          start[pos]['name00'] in other_name:
        link = start[pos]
        pos += 1

    link_key = None


# Print the resulting pairs
for link in result:
    print(link["name00"], link["name01"])
```

Output:

```
test1 test2
test1 test3
test4 test5
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but here is what I understood:

two items *i* and *j* from *results* are considered equal if:

- (`i['name00'] == j['name00']` and `i['name01'] == j['name01']`) or
- (`i['name01'] == j['name00']` and `i['name00'] == j['name01']`).

Is it right?

In that case, you can define a key which compares the values 'name00'/'name01' by sorting them, then use that key to store all the items in a dictionary to eliminate duplicates.

For instance:

```py
def key(item):
    return frozenset([item['name00'], item['name01']])


by_key = {key(item): item for item in results}

pprint.pprint(sorted(by_key.values()))
```

You get:

```py
[{'name00': 'test2', 'name01': 'test1'},
 {'name00': 'test3', 'name01': 'test1'},
 {'name00': 'test3', 'name01': 'test2'},
 {'name00': 'test5', 'name01': 'test4'}]
```

Comment: Yes it is right, but there is still extra 3-2 in results.

Comment: @OndřejŠevčík, can you explain further? I don't understand why.

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE because I pass this data to visualisation script that I can't change and it makes visualisation wrong if it is in there.